# Want "Cancel" Button to stop downloading images in c#

Tags: c#, button

Using following code I am downloading images from database over HTTPWebRequest.

```
 BackgroundWorker bgWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

 string baseUrl = "http://some path";
 int numIterations = 10;
 for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++)
        {
         if (bw.CancellationPending == true)
           {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
           }

         else
            {
             HttpWebRequest request = null;
             foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
                   {
                      string url = string.Format(baseUrl, fileName);
                      request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                      request.Method = "GET";
                      request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                      request.CookieContainer = container;

                      response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                      Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                      Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);

                      img.Save("some path" + fileName);

                      ZoomThumbnail = img;
                      ZoomSmall = img;
                      ZoomLarge = img;

                      ZoomThumbnail = GenerateThumbnail(ZoomThumbnail, 86, false);

                      ZoomSmall  = GenerateThumbnail(ZoomSmall, 400, false);

                      ZoomLarge = GenerateThumbnail(ZoomLarge, 1200, false);

                      if (img != null)
                      ZoomThumbnail.Save("some path" + fileName + "_Thumb.jpg");
                      ZoomSmall.Save("some path" + fileName + "_ZoomSmall.jpg");
                      ZoomLarge.Save("some path" + fileName + "_ZoomLarge.jpg");
                      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                    }
                }
```

This code is located under ButtonProcess_click and is working perfectly fine. There is one more button "Cancel". Whenever user clicks on "Cancel", I want process of downloading and saving images to stop. Can anyone help? Here is code for cancel button that does nothing but to disable "Process" button.

```
ButtonProcess.Enabled = false;
Button btnSender = sender as Button;
btnSender.Enabled = false;
bw.CancelAsync();
```

Comment: is this wpf, winforms, etc?

Comment: Yes.. I am using a Form with two buttons and a picturebox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the line `bw.CancelAsync()` I guess use use a `BackgroundWorker`. I also guess that the above code is executed by the background worker.

In no place in that code, however, I can see that you're actually *checking* whether the process should be canceled. Also, you're downloading the image in one go in this line:

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

This does not support cancellation. So problems are:

1. You can not cancel the loop over all the files as you're not checking whether the background worker should be cancelled
2. You can not cancel an individual image download, as you're downloading it in one go

Solutions:

1. In your loop, add condition that exits the loop if the background worker is cancelled
2. Change the image download so that you get chunks of bytes, call this in a loop and also check for cancellation there.

Possible solution for the first:

```
if (bw.CancellationPending)
{
    return;
}
```

Possible solution for the second:

```
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
int bytesRead = 0;
do
{
    bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // Save the bytes to a memory stream
    }
}
while (bytesRead > 0 && !bw.CancellationPending)

if (!bw.CancellationPending)
    img = Image.FromStream(<yourMemoryStream>);
```

Comment: in .net 4.5, `Stream` has a new method `ReadAsync` with an overload that accepts a cancellation token http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193669%28v=vs.110%29.aspx These overloads are `awaitable`.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar . Please go through edits I have made in question

Comment: @GauravK. This change is not complete. You need not only cancel the iterations, but also the `foreach` loop over the files and you haven't implemented the blockwise read from the stream at all. Also, please refrain from incorporating the solution into your question, as otherwise the answers will be invalid, as the code in your question works. Just try out what I've suggested in your project and see whether it works.